# sencha-touch: Login request-response

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I am very new to **sencha-touch** & started to build simple **Login** form.
My UI is ready but now I am stuck on how to write code for login request response.

As important, how can I point to specific url to make POST/GET request?

Also how to get & parse the json data.?

I read the sench-touch documentation but I didnt understood, how to use that model, store, proxy.
Suggestions upon how to create model, store, proxy to make simple login are very helpful.

Thanks in advance.

***Edited to insert image:***

[image]

```
var loginForm = Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
    fullscreen: true,

    items: [{
        xtype: 'fieldset',
        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'textfield',
                name : 'name',
                label: 'Username'
            },
            {
                xtype: 'passwordfield',
                name : 'password',
                label: 'Password'
            }
        ]
    }]
});

loginForm.add({
                xtype: 'button',
                text: 'Login',
                ui: 'confirm',
                badgeText: '1',
                // handler: function(){
                    // // alert("handler invoked");
                // },

                listeners : {
                tap : function() {

                var form = Ext.getCmp('form-id');
                var values = form.getValues();
                Ext.Ajax.request({
                      url: 'https://102.XXX.X.XX:XXXX/QuizMasterServer/rest/login',
                      params: values,

                      success: function(response){
                          var text = response.responseText;
                          Ext.Msg.alert('Success', text);
                     },

                     failure : function(response) {
                           Ext.Msg.alert('Error','Error while submitting the form');
                           console.log(response.responseText);
                     }
              });
}
}
});



loginForm.add({
    xtype: 'toolbar',

    // id:'loginPressed',

    docked: 'bottom',
    // layout: { pack: 'center' },
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'button',
            text: 'Login',
            ui: 'confirm',
            // action: 'login',

            handler: function() {
                loginForm.setValues({
                    name: 'vs',
                    password: 'vs'
                })
            }
        },
        {
            xtype: 'button',
            text: 'Clear',
            ui:'decline',
            handler: function() {
                loginForm.reset();
            }
        },

        {
            xtype: 'button',
            centered: true,
            text: 'Sign Up',
            handler: function() {
                alert('New User?');
            }
        },
        {
            xtype: 'container',
            html: 'New User? ',
            style: {
                color: 'yellow',
            }
        },
    ]
});
```

Comment: please add the javascript code

Comment: That is only I am asking that I dont know how to write the javascript code to perform login request -response

Comment: But still I added the code I wrote to draw the posted UI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there!

add your code to the success callback. 
Note, success() callback if fired if ajax returns ok, otherwise failure(). Callback callback() fire in both cases.

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: 'https://102.XXX.X.XX:XXXX/QuizMasterServer/rest/login',
    params: values,

    success: function(response){
        var text = response.responseText;
        // for example
        var result = Ext.decode(text);  // json parsing
        if (result.ok) {
            //create new widget
            var homeView = Ext.widget('homePage', {...});
            Ext.Viewport.remove(formLogin);
            Ext.Viewport.add(homeView);
            ///... etc
            homeView.show()
        }
        Ext.Msg.alert('Success', text);
    },

    failure : function(response) {
        Ext.Msg.alert('Error','Error while submitting the form');
        console.log(response.responseText);
    }
});
```

Disclaimer. Of course the code is not tested...

cheers, Oleg

Comment: Hey thanks.. I have not wrote the stmt `**method:'POST'**` after url stmt.. Will this missing stmt affect anything?

Comment: If your server accept POST it will of course. Look at your server config. And you can use any HTTP type, GET/POST/PUT etc. Have a look at the http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.Ajax for more info

Comment: I do not advice using model/proxy/store at the login, but right this is possible. Better to return credentials data from this query. In my application I got from server an session token and save it to the internal application's variable. All next ajax queries will include it as a parameter or cookie. This depends on the you app design/server part

Answer (score 1):

Exemplo usando ajax request:

Example using ajax request:

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
        url: domain.com/auth/signIn/',
        method: 'post',
        scope: this,
        params: {
            email: username,
            password: password
        },

        success: function (response) {

            var result = Ext.JSON.decode(response.responseText);

            if (result.meta.code==200)
            {

                /**
                 * Salvando dados do usuário em localStorage
                 * Save user data on localStorage
                 */
                window.localStorage.setItem('myID', result.response.id);
                window.localStorage.setItem('email', result.response.email);
                window.localStorage.setItem('token', result.response.token);
                window.localStorage.setItem('fName', result.response.fName);
                window.localStorage.setItem('lName', result.response.lName);
                window.localStorage.setItem('photo', result.response.photo);
                window.localStorage.setItem('gender', result.response.gender);
                window.localStorage.setItem('relationship', result.response.relationship);
                window.localStorage.setItem('interest', result.response.interest);

                this.signInSuccess();                    
                this.verifyDeviceToken(result.response.id, 'signin');

            }
            else
            {

                 this.signInFailure('Error', 'The data reported are invalid');

            }
        },

        failure: function (response) {


        }
    });
```